# Why did Rhavas stop using his Curse ability?

Tags: harry-turtledove, videssos

I'm aware that the real life reason is that the books were written in reverse order. However, you would think that at some point towards the end of [Bridge of the Separator](http://turtledove.wikia.com/wiki/Bridge_of_the_Separator), Rhavas would make some kind of comment about no longer having the ability to curse people and/or things, given that it plays such a huge role in the book but never seems to appear in later books.

**Was there an explanation that I simply missed, or was it never explained?**

Comment: It looks like you've got sufficient rights, you should probably add some information to the tag you've created.

Comment: I didn't create a tag I think...?

Comment: You've got the only question using it. :)

Comment: Just shows me there's no summary but doesn't allow me to add anything. Perhaps because I'm on my cell phone?

Answer (score 1):

Only a theory, but: He was badly hurt and almost died. I think that was when he lost the ability to just wish people dead. His body rebuilt itself, but not quite as powerful as before.

Comment: *Spoilers* I don't remember him being hurt, aside from when he was initially captured. That's when he made his deal for extended life. But after that, he was able to cast the darkness magic to escape, free Videssos, then curse the city. Which would seem that it was what used up the last of what he had, except he then escaped, joined the Kubrat by cursing their shaman, and brought down Imbros with his curse.